# sass-loader fails to work (You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, sass-loader

Hi all I am following the instructions as posted on https://github.com/yibn2008/fast-sass-loader for this sass loaders. The reason I choose it is because I am using webpack 1. Currently my module looks like

```
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
    include: SRC_DIR
  },
  { 
      test: /\.(scss|sass)$/i,
      loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "fast-sass-loader"]
  }
]
}
```

when I go to look at my localhost I get this errror

```
ERROR in ./src/common/css/common.sass
Module parse failed: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\backup\src\common\css\comm
on.sass Invalid number (1:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Invalid number (1:7)
```

Not sure what the problem is, can any point me in the right direction or tell me of another sass loader that works with webpack 1?

**Update 1**
I realized that in my import statement when I do `'!style!css-loader!fast-sass!'` it works but I do not want to do that every time. Why will the loader in webpack not work?

Comment: Please post if you got the solution

Comment: Sorry no solution I added !style!css!fast-sass in every import statement for a temp fix.